# Prove $n=m$ if $(q^n-1)(q^n-q)\cdots (q^n-q^{n-1}) = (q^m-1)(q^m-q)\cdots (q^m-q^{m-1})$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $m, n, q \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$. If $(q^n-1)(q^n-q)\cdots (q^n-q^{n-1}) = (q^m-1)(q^m-q)\cdots (q^m-q^{m-1})$, how to prove $n=m$?

Comment: For fixed $q$, if you can show that $n\mapsto (q^n-1)(q^n-q)\cdots (q^n-q^{n-1})$ is increasing then it is injective...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A_n$ your first expression. Then we have $A_n=A_m$. Note that we have to suppose that $q\geq 2$, otherwise the result is not true. It is easy to show that $A_n=q^{n(n-1)/2}\prod_{k=1}^n(q^k-1)$. Now let $p$ a prime dividing $q$, and for $x\in \mathbb{Z}$ not $0$, $v_p(x)=a$ the integer $\geq 0$ such that $p^a$ divide $x$, and $p^{a+1}$ do not divide $x$. Show that $v_p(A_n)=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}v_p(q)$. It is easy to finish.

Comment: Why $\upsilon_p (A_n) = \frac{n(n-1)}{2} \upsilon_p (q)$? Maybe $p$ is a prime diving $q-1$.

Comment: No: I have taken $p$ a prime dividing $q$. Then $p$ do not divide any of the terms $q^k-1$, $k=1,..,n$.

Comment: @ Kelenner Ok, I got it. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Bing You are welcome

Answer (score 1):

If $q$ is a prime power then we have
$$
|GL(n,\mathbb{F}_q)|=(q^n-1)(q^n-q)\cdots (q^n-q^{n-1}) = (q^m-1)(q^m-q)\cdots (q^m-q^{m-1})=|GL(m,\mathbb{F}_q)|
$$
The chain of subgroups $GL(1,q)\subset GL(2,q)\subset \cdots$ is strictly increasing, so that the map $n\mapsto A_n$ is injective. Here $A_n$ is the order of $GL(n,q)$. Hence $A_n=A_m$ implies that $n=m$.

Comment: @ Dietrich Burde Why $\textrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{F}_q) \subseteq \textrm{GL}(m,\mathbb{F}_q) \subseteq \textrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{F}_q)$?

Comment: Because for $n=1,2,3,\cdots$ we have a chain of subgroups $GL(1,q)\subseteq GL(2,q)\subseteq GL(3,q)\cdots$.

Comment: @ Dietrich Burde However, I don't know $n \leq m$ or $n \geq m$.

Comment: You need not know this. As said in the above comment by @myself , $n\mapsto A_n$ is then injective, where $A_n$ is the order of $GL(n,q)$, because the chain is strictly increasing (obviously). Hence $A_n=A_m$ implies that $n=m$.

Comment: I thought about this, but $q$ is not assumed to be prime.

Comment: @i707107 No, $q$ is not assumed to be prime, but $q=p^r$ for some prime $p$ would do. We could replace $\mathbb{F}_q$ by $\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$ with arbitrary $q\in\mathbb{Z}$ for the matrices?

Comment: Probably not, would $GL(2,\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})$ with arbitrary $q\in\mathbb{Z}$ have the cardinality? The formula for the number of elements in $GL(2,\mathbb{F}_q)$ requires $\mathbb{F}_q$ to be a field.

Comment: First, $GL(n,\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})$ when $q$ is composite, it decomposes to the product of $GL(n,\mathbb{Z}/p^a\mathbb{Z})$ with $p^a$ exactly dividing $q$. This does not mean that $|GL(n,\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})|=(q^n-1)(q^n-q)\cdots (q^n-q^{n-1})$. This is because the expression is not multiplicative in $q$. So, you cannot just break it down to prime factors and piece them together.

Comment: Second, even if you break down into prime powers, $|GL(n,\mathbb{Z}/p^a\mathbb{Z})|$ may not be $(p^{an}-1)(p^{an}-p^a)\cdots (p^{an}-p^{a(n-1)})$. For example, with $q=p^2$, we have $|GL(1,\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z})| = \phi(p^2) = p^2 - p \neq p^2 -1$.

Comment: @i707107 Yes, I know, you are right. The first time I saw the question I really thought $q$ would be a prime power. Thank you for your efforts to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $q$ is a variable then take the largest power of $q$ on both sides. Then equate those powers.

Comment: @ Ashar Tafhim   Here $q$ is a positive integer..